# Matrix concatenation using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, concatenation, mathnet-numerics

I would like to perform row-wise and column-wise matrix concatenation using `.NET Framework` with `MathNet` library. For example, if I have 3 matrices `A`, `B`, `C` of dimension `nxn`, I would like create a new matrix `D` of dimension `2nx2n` where

```
// I have used MATLAB syntax here to explain the operation
// D = [A B; B C];
```

I have currently defined the matrices `A`, `B`, `C` as `DenseMatrix` class and would like to proceed from here.

Answer (score 4):

That's one way to do it in VB.Net:

```
Dim D =
    MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Matrix.Build.DenseOfMatrixArray(
        New MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix(Of Double)(,)
             {{A, B}, {B, C}})
```

Comment: where `{ {A, B} }` places B right of A
and `{ {A}, {B} }` places B to the bottom of A

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could do:

```
// To shorten build notation.
var M = Matrix<double>.Build;

// Define these matrices how you want it.
Matrix<double> A = ...;
Matrix<double> B = ...;
Matrix<double> C = ...;

// Define a 2D array of matrices.
Matrix<double>[,] MatrixArray2D =
{  
    { A, B },
    { B, C }
};

// Use the 2D array to construct the concatenated matrix.
Matrix<double> ConcatinatedMatrix = M.DenseOfMatrixArray(MatrixArray2D);
```